# XMLParser error with NSThread

Tags: iphone, multithreading, xml-parsing, program-entry-point

I have an application in which I load my XML data via the NSXMLParser into an UITableView. This all worked perfectly. Because I wanted to add a ActivityIndicator I have to place my loading data on a different thread then the main. After I did this the XML get loaded as well as my application but I see nothing in my table. When I click on a different tab of my tabbarcontroller and then click back to the table the data in the table becomes visible. What is going wrong?

My file:

```
#import "DAFAppDelegate.h"
#import "RootViewController.h"
#import "XMLParser.h"


@implementation DAFAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize navigationController;
@synthesize rootViewController;
@synthesize rootTabController;
@synthesize stages;

+ (void) showAlert
{
    UIAlertView *av = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Connection" message:@"Could not retrieve data" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];
    [av show];
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [window addSubview:[rootTabController view]];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(parseXML) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}

- (void) parseXML
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://web.me.com/ijar/Stages.xml"];
    NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

    //Initialize the delegate.
    XMLParser *parser = [[XMLParser alloc] initXMLParser];

    //Set delegate
    [xmlParser setDelegate:parser];

    //Start parsing the XML file.
    BOOL success = [xmlParser parse];

    if(success)
    {
        NSLog(@"No Errors");
    }
    else
    {
        [DAFAppDelegate showAlert];
        NSLog(@"Error Error Error!!!");
    }  

    [pool release];

}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [navigationController release];
    [rootViewController release];
    [rootTabController release];
    [window release];
    [stages release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you call `reloadData` on your table view? Also you should send the message to the table view using `-performSelectorOnMainThread:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)arg waitUntilDone:(BOOL)wait`.

You should send these messages if your parser succeeded.

```
if (succeed)
{
   [myTableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

It might be better to call your table view's datasource object to update it's data store and then from there, tell the table view to update its data.

Comment: No where should I place this reloadData and -performSelectorOnMainThread:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)arg waitUntilDone:(BOOL)wait? Sorry for the dumb questions. But I am a newbie on this. Starting to learn by doing and reading books. All help is welcome :-)

Comment: I have placed it in the code now under the parser succeeded message. and my dataReload method looks like this in my rootViewController: - (void) updateTable:(NSMutableArray *)data {
 appDelegate.stages = data;
 [self.tableView reloadData]; 
} Now my compiler gives an error the moment the data is loaded.

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ShadowedTableView updateTable:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5066e00'

Comment: It's telling you it cannot find the updateTable method in the class ShadowedTableView.

Comment: Ah yes. When I change this to self.rootViewController (where the method updateTable is) the compiler has no error. But now the end result is still the same. Data loads but no table visible. And when I select another tab and back the data is still not visible, which is different from when I changed it with your directions. Would it be easier if I send you my project file?

Comment: I don't think I'll have time to look at your project. Try debugging the problem. Place a break point at the data source's  -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: and make sure that is called. This is where each cell will be loaded with data.